# Submit button is not working after using Bootstrap in Bottle template

Tags: python, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, bottle

I am using bottle framework and python to make a website. After using bootstrap, the submit button of my form is not working.
Here is my code in the button3.tpl file:

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
         <h1>Insert Artist</h1>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="container"
          <form role="form" method="post" action="/result4">
             <div class="form-group">
        <laber>National ID</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ID" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <laber>Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" value=""><br>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <laber>Surname</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Surname" value=""><br>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Birth Year</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="number" name="Birth" min="1900" max="2016"><br>
       </div>
         <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Update Information">
       </form>
       </div>
       <hr>
      </body>
```

Why does it not redirect in the proper link ?

Comment: You seem to have mis matched tags   <laber>National ID</label> should be <label>National ID</label> you have several of them... correct and check

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine.